How to model a bidirectional, one-to-one relationship in DynamoDB?
I'm building a WebSocket API Gateway in AWS. When a device connects, API Gateway assigns the connection a unique connection ID.  I need to store the relationship between the connection ID and device in a table:



Connection ID
Device ID
Created At




123
ABC
2024-10-11T21:48:08.500Z


456
DEF
2024-10-11T21:48:08.500Z



All connection IDs and device IDs are unique. Connection IDs have a one-to-one relationship with device IDs.
In AWS's examples, the connection ID is often used as the partition key in DynamoDB, allowing for fast lookups and deletions by connection ID. However, I also need fast lookups and deletions by device ID. If the connection ID is the partition key, finding a connection by device ID would require scanning the entire table.
In other words, the operations I need to support are (written using SQL):
SELECT connection_id FROM connections WHERE device_id = xxxx;
SELECT device_id FROM connections WHERE connection_id = xxxx;
DELETE FROM connections WHERE device_id = xxxx;
DELETE FROM connections WHERE connection_id = xxxx;

I've looked into adding a Global Secondary Index on the device ID, but GSI updates are eventually consistent. This means if I delete a connection by connection ID, someone might still see the connection if, immediately after the delete, they look up the connection using a device ID.
My question: Is it possible to model this relationship efficiently in DynamoDB, or would a SQL database be more appropriate?

Let's dial this back a second: are you sure you need a 1-1 relationship? Specifically 1 on both sides, not 0..1? If you've answered "yes" twice, what would be the benefit of distinguishing between a device and a connection from a data structure perspective? If you answered "no" at least once, then you'll need to refine your question to explain exactly what relationship you're looking to model.

Also, I cannot confirm this from my end, but I want to point out that often when I hear people asking for 1-1 relationships, they tend to only think about current state and not historical state; so please do evaluate if you've glossed over this as well. For example, what happens if a device goes offline, and then reconnects?

Hell yeah it is! Here's how:
Store two items per connection:
Item 1: PK = 'CONN#<connection_id>', SK = 'META', Attributes: DeviceID, CreatedAt
Item 2: PK = 'DEVICE#<device_id>', SK = 'META', Attributes: ConnectionID, CreatedAt
Operations:
Lookup by Connection ID: Use GetItem with PK = 'CONN#123', SK = 'META'.
Lookup by Device ID: Use GetItem with PK = 'DEVICE#ABC', SK = 'META'.
Delete: Use TransactWriteItems to atomically delete both of em
Should give pretty consistent lookup / deletions by either ID, without scans or GSIs. I think Dynamo is actually a good choice over SQL in this case since ops have immediate, strong consistency.
